# Insert custom text to JCE using Javascript

Tags: joomla-2.5, javascript, tinymce

How to insert custom text to JCE v. 2.3.4.4 using javascript?

I have opened the page source and saw that the editor is an iframe. Text is in `<body id="tinymce">`.

I was trying something like:

```
$("body#tinymce").html("mytext");
```

but it doesn't work. Of course, it is executed on domReady.

Comment: is that element is accessible through $("body#tinymce") selector??

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

```
var id = "yourTextAreaId";
var tmce_el = tinyMCE.get(id);
if (tmce_el != undefined)
{
    tmce_el.execCommand('mceSetContent', false, value);
}
else
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

Comment: You may accepted your own answer to mark your isssue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to use the `Joomla.editors.instances`

You will be able to validate that it has the textAreaId loaded and then update with the `setValue` method.

```
if (Joomla.editors.instances.hasOwnProperty('yourTextAreaId')) {
    Joomla.editors.instances['yourTextAreaId'].setValue(value);
} else {
    // do you custom script as fail-safe
}
```

I have tested this with codemirror, tinyMCE, none (when no editor is set) and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a custom button plugin provided by the creators of JCE...

https://github.com/widgetfactory/jce-custom